# Set menus for multiple toolbars on android

Tags: android, toolbar

In my activity I use the following code for my two toolbars.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");

    toolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_bottom);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);
    ...
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
 }
```

I want it to use menu_main.xml for the top toolbar and menu_bottom for bottom toolbar but for both top and bottom toolbar it uses menu_main.xml.

Can somebody explain how to do it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Toolbar Action icon not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128809/android-toolbar-action-icon-not-working)

Comment: @Elltz how did you find it duplicate?

Comment: as, the code in the question is exactly the same as the other-(also variable names), also they are all looking at/for the same solution even though the title might not be that convincing, so its either  a dupe of this or a dupe of that, & why are you not convinced about it Sir?@PareshMayani

Comment: @Elltz thanks for your link...But I Agree with Paresh, If you compare answers...the question is different, :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As you are using two `ToolBar`s set the menu like this

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

The above toolbar inflate menu from `onCreateOptionsMenu`, menu CallBack listener will be `onOptionsItemSelected`

Now Second `ToolBar`

```
 toolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_bottom);
 toolbar2.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);//changed
 //toolbar2 menu items CallBack listener 
 toolbar2.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
        if(arg0.getItemId() == R.id.item_id){

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got this error:`Error:(37, 49) error: cannot find symbol class OnMenuItemClickListener` and `item_id` in my debuger is red color.

Comment: and where define 'bottom_menu' for `tool_bar_bottom`

Comment: please check updated answer.. and `item_id` is id from bottom_menu file. About OnMenuItemClickListener you need to import it

Comment: @Hilal make sure you are not adding custom views in-side toolbar and menu id is matching with menu file.

Comment: Yes it was exactly what you said but still did not worked. So I tried another way, which is adding ImageView inside Toolbar2. And then I setOnClickLİstener on ImageView by calling it from its id. Actually maybe there were no need for Toolbar2 I could use just ImageView but I did not remove Toolbar anyway