# How to pairing bottom app bar with top app bar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomappbar

In the picture what I want to do.

[image: Pic]

I have two menu.xml files. How to add the first menu at top app bar and the second at the bottom app bar? Can I do this in one activity or I should create activity with top app bar + fragment with a bottom app bar? Thanks.

Comment: I dont think the bottom bar is an app bar in the way you are thinking. Just a custom view/bar with floating button. You can create a `LinearLayout` with `ImageButton` or something similar

Comment: If possible can you please share the xml code?@Doomsknight

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I solved this problem.

For toolbar on top of the activity I use `setSupportActionBar()` inflate menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and processing `MenuItem` click in `onOptionsItemSelected()`

For BottomAppBar (new material component) I use bottomAppBar.replaceMenu() in order to set the menu. For processing `MenuItem` click: `bottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener()`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bom52.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> How to add the first menu at top app bar and the second at bottom app
>   bar? Can I do this in one acivity or I should create `Activity` with top
>   app bar + fragment with bottom ap bar?

You'll probably be able to do that with `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for the top of the `Activity`, (called `Toolbar`) then use a `NavigationDrawer` and another `View` (Can be a custom view like `LinearLayout` with `ImageView`s or etc) or another `Toolbar` in the bottom.

Or, using custom view and inflating `menu`s by `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**This might help** for two `Toolbar`s in one `Activity`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37002188/4409113

**Also:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/34906999/4409113

---

In your case (as we can see in the picture), i believe there is a `Toolbar` at top of `Activity`, with `CoordinatorLayout` which has `FloatingActionButton` in the middle and there will be just inflating in java-kotlin side left.